# Execution failed for task ':react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: react-native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  `Execution failed for task ':react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugKotlin'`.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> Compilation error. See log for more details

```
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

[

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org]https://help.gradle.org)

BUILD FAILED in 3m 54s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\Zsola\Desktop\NoruHotels\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\Zsola\Desktop\NoruHotels\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Zsola\Desktop\NoruHotels\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Zsola\Desktop\NoruHotels\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
```

info Run CLI with `--verbose flag` for more details.

i tried this with ai

This error occurs when there is an issue with the Kotlin compilation process for the react-native-gesture-handler library. Here are some steps you can take to resolve the issue:

1. Make sure that you have the correct version of Kotlin Gradle Plugin installed. You can check the version in your project's build.gradle file under dependencies.
2. Try cleaning and rebuilding your project by running the following commands in your project directory:

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
cd ..
react-native run-android
```

3. If the issue persists, try updating your Kotlin version by adding the following line to your project's build.gradle file:

`ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.21'`

Then update the Kotlin Gradle Plugin version to match:

`classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21"`

4. If none of the above steps work, try disabling Kotlin compilation for the react-native-gesture-handler library by adding the following line to your project's build.gradle file:

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.facebook.react', module: 'react-native-gesture-handler'
}
```

Then run `react-native run-android` again.

Hopefully one of these steps will resolve the issue for you.

Answer (score 8):

I solved it by upgrading my react-native-gesture-handler to version 2.9.0.

1. **Update `package.json`:**
   Open your project's `package.json` file and find `the dependency for react-native-gesture-handler`. Change the version number to "2.9.0" (don't forget to remove `^`). It should look like this:

   ```
   "dependencies": {
     "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.9.0",
     // other dependencies...
   }
   ```
2. Uninstall the `node_modules` folder.
3. Run `npm install`
4. Try building your project now

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why, but this seems to solve my problem.

1: Add a String to android/build.gradle

```
kotlinVersion = "1.8.10"
```

2: Delete node_modules folder

`rm -r node_modules`

3:`npm i`

4:`npx react-native run-android`

Also run VS code (if you're working in it) as an administrator.

Answer (score 2):

updating my android build.gradle buildscript to

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = '33.0.0'
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
  }
....
}
```

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

**Install** the below **packages** with ***specific versions*** that will resolve your error :

```
npm i @react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.11 @react-navigation/native@6.0.10 @react-navigation/stack@6.2.1 react-native-gesture-handler@2.4.2 react-native-safe-area-context@4.2.5 react-native-screens@3.2.0 react-navigation@4.4.4
```

and import :

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
```

Answer (score 0):

If the error is related to cxx modules, add this `classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1")` on `android/build.gradle`.

Also check this [issue](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/2427)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line

=> kotlin_version = '1.5.21'

or

=> kotlinVersion = "1.8.10"

to

=> android/build.gradle

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).